# Use percentage/relative values in Styling of <View /> on iOS in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I want to do something like this in `react-native`

```
<View
    style = { width: '100%', padding: 10, borderRadius: '25%' }> 
    {...}
</View>
```

But I get (on iOS)

> JSON value '25%' of type NSString cannot be converted to NSNumber

Is there a way to use relative/percentage values as styling input for `borderRadius`?

Comment: which version of RN are you using? tried with expo with above code and got no error https://snack.expo.io/@thainq00/style

Comment: @QuangThái With expo I did not have any problems too. With `RN 0.63.4` I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that, use `ref` in order to have a reference to that element, then you can measure its width (not in percentage) and you can calculate the border radius.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef();

  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.measure((x, y, w, h) => {
      setWidth(w);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View
        ref={ref}
        style={{
          width: '80%',
          padding: 10,
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          borderRadius: width / 4, // 25%
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a quick researching, i found that [`borderRadius` style expects number as a value, not a String](https://github.com/refinery29/react-native-cheat-sheet#how-to-make-circle-image-with-react-native)

So if you want to custom the value of `borderRadius`, you can do sth like this:

```
<View style={{
  width: 300,
  height: 300,
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  padding: 10,
  borderRadius: 300/4     // equal 25% of its size 
}}>
```

Comment: Yes, the error is suggesting that. However, as you can see from my code, the `width` of the `<View />` is `100%` which means I cannot calculate the `borderRadius` like you are doing it.

Comment: i think you have to get the width with number value somewhere, then set borderRadius based on that width